# Passing Variable between pages in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to opencart .

Recently i tried some modification to learn it.

[image]

I want to add a new line named as **use** **reference id** . I want to save this reference id in the database with the sale record.

But i dont understand how can i pass the parameter from the  cart page to the checkout page.

Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: you can use session or cookies http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate the entire coupon extension (controller, class, model, template); rename the class (from Coupon to ReferenceId) and rename all of the 'coupon' variables to 'referenceid' - this would add the form and all other utensils needed to achieve what you are trying to do.

You can pass it as a session, just like coupon does and it will be recorded by the database model (don't forget to actually create it as a row in the database, with something like phpmyadmin).

You can then reference it on any page you want, by adding a query to the table it resides on (unless there's already an existing query to it's parent table, then just add it as another row call).